# @property setter on ObjectifiedElement doesn't work

Tags: python, lxml

I am using lxml.objectify in my Python app and have defined custom element classes for selected XML elements. When I add a property to the custom element class, the getter is called but the setter is not. Instead of calling the setter, a new child element with the name of the property I defined is added to the element.

I'm assuming my getter definition is properly overriding the `__getattr__` method of ObjectifiedElement but for some reason the `__setattr__` method of ObjectifiedElement is taking precedence over my setter.

What would it take to get it to execute my setter instead?

```
class CT_TextParagraph(objectify.ObjectifiedElement):
    """<a:p> custom element class"""
    def _get_algn(self):
        """
        Value of algn attribute on <a:pPr> child element
        """
        if not hasattr(self, 'pPr'):
            return None
        return self.pPr.get('algn')

    def _set_algn(self, value):
        """
        Set value of algn attribute on <a:pPr> child element
        """
        raise AssertionError('in _set_algn()')
        # if not hasattr(self, 'pPr'):
        #     pPr = _Element('a:pPr')
        #     self.insert(0, pPr)
        self.pPr.set('algn', value)

    #: Paragraph horizontal alignment value, like ``TAT.CENTER``
    algn = property(_get_algn, _set_algn)
```

Comment: Does `objectify.ObjectifiedElement` derive from `object`? If not, you have an old-style class. By using `class CT_TextParagraph(objectify.ObjectifiedElement, object):` you make it a new-style class where it should work.

Comment: You have to moke sure that `object` is in `CT_TextParagraph.mro()`

Comment: @glglgl, @User: ObjectifiedElement inherits from ElementBase, which inherits from _Element. They look like this `cdef class lxml.etree._Element [ object LxmlElement ]:`, and this `cdef class lxml.etree.ElementBase(_Element) [ object LxmlElementBase ]:`. I'm not familiar with the Python syntax for classes implemented in C, but I'm guessing that's what these are. `object` is not in the mix there that I can see by inspection. Think it would work if I just added `object` as a base class for `CT_TextParagraph` after `ObjectifiedElement`?

Comment: @scanny Just try it out... don't think you can break anything...

Comment: Didn't work. Turns out object is already in the `__mro__` for `ObjectifiedElement` anyway. I think the net is that having a __setattr__ defined anywhere in your base classes overrides property setters being called in inheriting classes. I ended up overriding __setattr__ in `CT_TextParagraph` and routing property setter messages to the setter method "manually". Thanks for the help though, helped put me on the right track :)